# Not able to create LoadBalancer on DigitalOcen using Python

Tags: python, digital-ocean

I am working on digitalocean platform, I need to create LoadBalancer by using python I am using the digitalocean-python library but I am not able to create LB using python script,can anyone help mme out how can i create LB using python-like script, below is my code

```
import digitalocean
droplet = digitalocean.LoadBalancer(token="API- Token",
name= 'check',
region= 'BLR1'
forwarding_rules= ['entry_protocol:http',
'entry_port:80',
'target_protocol:http',
'target_port:80']))
droplet.create()
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You had syntax errors, before forwarding_rules and after region (missing comma), and parentheses mismatch:

```
import digitalocean
droplet = digitalocean.LoadBalancer(token="API- Token",
                                    name='check',
                                    region='BLR1',
                                    forwarding_rules=['entry_protocol:http',
                                                      'entry_port:80',
                                                      'target_protocol:http',
                                                      'target_port:80'
                                                      ]
                                    )

droplet.create()
```

Not sure if it will work now, but it is at least two steps closer.

Comment: Hey thanks for your responce I will check and let you know